# Object keeps falling out of scope in vbscript/asp classic

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

So I have a list of items I am pulling from from a database that need to be sorted in a very specific and convoluted manner. To combat this, I made an object that contains all of the information in the record set and am organizing them by arrays, which I can print out in the order I want. The problem is that after my "do while rs.eof" where I set all the objects to whatever I need, they fall out of scope when the loop ends, even if the arrays themselves don't. I have checked that the objects are being set in the loop and they work, but they just cease to be by the time I get to the Response.Write(). I'm not including the beginning of the loop because it is more or less the else statement copy-pasted with the array changed. Any tips?

```
Else
            ReDim Preserve f0(Ubound(f0)+1)
            Set tab = new TabletHelper
            Set f0(Ubound(f0)) = tab
            item  = rs("Item")
            dest = rs("Destination")
            time = rs("DateTime")
            f0(Ubound(f0)).setItem(item)
            f0(Ubound(f0)).setLocation(dest)
            f0(Ubound(f0)).setDateTime(time)
        End If
        rs.movenext
    loop

    rs.Close

    If Ubound(a045) > 0 then
    for i = 1 to Ubound(a045)
            Response.Write("<tr><td>"&a045(i).iNum()&"</td><td>"&a045(i).dest()&"</td><td>"&a045(i).dateT()&"</td></tr>")
    next
```

Comment: Which object? You have `f0` *(which is an `Array`)* being set in the loop but you are trying to access `a045` *(which is also an `Array`)* afterwards...which is it? Ideally you should provide a [mcve] which this isn't.

Comment: The TabletHelper would be the object. It is an object that holds 3 datamembers (strings) and that's it. I was worried about including too much code that wasn't important and left out way too much. I'll have to be more considerate of this in the future.

Comment: Why set the tablethelper object in the recordset loop? I would set it before the loop, and (re) use it inside the loop.

Comment: @Naiya55 And there was your problem, you where looking in the wrong place...the resizing of the arrays will be where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out my issue. I had been initializing my arrays as size 0 originally, so that when the redim at the top of the code ran it would resize the array to size 1, making whatever element I was working with the first in the array. This gave me an error obviously and I fixed it by initializing the array to size 1 instead. However, I forgot to compensate for this and move the redim statement to the end of the if statement and change the bounds of the for loop. In short, I'm an idiot. On the bright side, I learned more about how to post on SO correctly!